# CSS overflow hidden causing text alignment problems

Tags: html, css, alignment, overflow

I have some pretty simple markup and I want long text to be truncated with "..."

```css
.topRow div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#name {
  max-width: 70%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="topRow">
  <div id="edit">
    <div id="pre">Before -</div>
    <div id="name">Some long text that should get truncated when it passes the max width</div>                    
    <div id="post">- After</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/xyPrv/3/

[image]

The problem is that when I add `overflow: hidden` to the div, it makes the text jump up a few pixels and is out of alignment with the rest of the text around it.

What is causing this vertical movement? Without manually pushing the text back down (with `position: relative; and top: 5px`), how can I cleanly get the text to be aligned?

Comment: Having faced the same problem, I would also like to understand WHY this is happening.

Comment: This answered it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152795/making-a-span-element-inline-block-and-overflow-hidden-will-displace-him

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.topRow div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#name {
    max-width: 70%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="topRow">
       <div id="edit">
              <div id="pre">Before -</div>
              <div id="name">Some long text that should get truncated when it passes the max width</div>                    
              <div id="post">- After</div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V79Hn/

Comment: Or any version of `vertical-align` whether top, middle or bottom depending on one's requirements.

Comment: Putting `vertical-align: middle;` on the 3 children div fixes the issue, but do you have any idea why `overflow: hidden;` would cause these alignment issues in the first place?

Comment: This still doesn't align the text the same as it is without the overflow property set

Comment: Interesting. In my case, I have an inline-block element withing inline container, and for me the better solution was: `vertical-align: bottom;`

Comment: @jbabey: because CSS sucks.  It has gotten better over the years, but this is a great example of why it is still kinda crappy.

Comment: Note that `vertical-align: middle` may be off-center, in which case you can use something along these lines: `vertical-align: -25%`. The percentage is dependent on the font, line-height and possibly even more factors, so it's easiest to determine this experimentally. Why `overflow: hidden` messes up the vertical alignment is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

If you change this:

```
.topRow div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

to this:

```
.topRow div {
    float:left;
}
```

Then it's as you want it.

Comment: I'd rather avoid float as it removes the elements from the flow of the page, causing other problems. Thanks, though!

Comment: This solution is a hack and not proper use of the css float property.

Comment: Thanks @StefanMorris for this comment on my answer 7 years ago :D

Answer (score 0):

Or just use:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  height: 3.6em;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
}
```